# use variable within a linq query

Tags: linq, .net-3.5

take this linq into consideration:

```
list.Where(sil => sil.XML.Element("ticket") != null && sil.XML.Element("ticket").Attribute("id").Value == smsRequestIn.TicketID)
```

if the "ticket" element is not null it searches for it twice and hence is not very effective. Is there a way to use some sort of variables within the linq expression so I can reference the variable instead of doing a double search for the "ticket" element or is linq intelligent enough to not do a double search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In LINQ Expression syntax you'd use `let` like this:

```
from sil in list
let ticket = sil.XML.Element("ticket")
where ticket != null && ticket.Attribute("id").Value == smsRequestIn.TicketID
select sil;
```

To replicate `let` using extension methods, you need to use `Select` and an anonymous type like so

```
list.Select(anon => new { ticket = anon.XML.Element("ticket"), anon })
    .Where(sil => sil.ticket != null && sil.ticket.Attribute("id").Value == smsRequestIn.TicketID)
    .Select(o=>o.anon);
```

Which is abundantly less clear.

Comment: +1 and accepted for providing both versions. I decided to go with the LINQ Expression syntax for clarity reasons

Answer (score 3):

I'd rewrite your query to the following:

```
var result = from sil in list
             let element = sil.XML.Element("ticket")
             where element != null &&
                   element.Attribute("id").Value == smsRequestIn.TicketID
             select sil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
Func<SilClass,bool> filter = sil => 
{ 
   XElement e = sil.XML.Element("ticket");
   return e != null && e.Attribute("id").Value == smsRequestIn.TicketID);
};

list.Where(filter);
```

but in this case I think you really benefit in using query syntax like other answers have suggested. It's much more clear.